# From India to Dubai, non Indian and non UAE citizen and allowed for VOA. But there's a trick

Tags: visas, india, covid-19, dubai, uae

I'm in India. I'm not Indian, not UAE resident, not from the Gulf countries either. I'm allowed to obtain visa on arrival in Dubai nowadays during the pandemic, and it's with certanty.

The thing, however, is: even though I'm allowed to obtain VOA in Dubai, it's still unclear whether or not I'm permitted to travel there ***concretely from India and now.***  And I have no one to ask about this who'd give a definitive answer.

**Note I already know that yes, I'm allowed to get VOA in Dubai,** as I'm in contact with my fellows of my country, with **the same residency and citizenship, on other travel forums, who are flying to Dubai nowadays, from other countries, daily, and do get VOA for 3 months.**

But even that may not be enough to take a flight **from India** during this time.

Look:

(1) FlyDubai and Emirates state on their websites that on "India - Dubai" they allow only indian residents and UAE ones. Already there's a restriction.

(2) At https://www.civilaviation.gov.in/en/about-air-transport-bubbles in regards to UAE - the same thing:

```
India has created an air bubble arrangement with the United Arab Emirates (UAE). This bubble is valid till 31.10.2020. Indian and UAE carriers are now permitted to operate flights between India and UAE and carry the following categories of persons on such flights:

A. From India to UAE:

i. UAE nationals.

ii. ICA approved UAE residents destined for UAE only.

iii. Any Indian national holding any type of valid UAE visa and destined for UAE only. It would be for the airlines concerned to ensure that there is no travel restriction for Indian nationals to enter UAE with the particular visa category before issue of ticket/ boarding pass to the Indian passenger.
```

(3) Vistara, GoAir, IndiGo, AirArabia and 1-2 others kind of have implied that accept everyone as long as he's permitted to enter Dubai with either visa or visa on arrival. But never do they imply it directly.

(4) The airlines don't bother to read my facebook messages and emails and always will answer with a generic response: "go ask the embassy of UAE". Then "we don't know, we just fly and follow the rules, check out our website". "Ahhh, yeah yeah, you'll be allowed. Ohhh, nooo, may be you won't be allowed. What's the rule you're talking about?" Never have they given me a clear answer. Not by phone either.

So, am I allowed to fly to Dubai from India? **And if I am, how about the (2)?**

P.S. I've already been denied boarding at a flight "India - Amsterdam - Turkey" (single ticket, with a transfer) because of a similar rule at (2) for Netherlands, **even though** I'm permitted to a) transit through Netherlands and b) get VOA in Turkey, nowadays too.

P.S.S I'm aware about a PCR test, a ticket to a third-country and so on.

Comment: What does Timatic say? It's what airlines will use to determine your eligibility.

Comment: @lambshaanxy do its rule apply now?

Comment: Yes, Timatic is where every country's rules are recorded.

Comment: @lambshaanxy this  - https://klm.traveldoc.aero ? it says allowed. But FlyDubai and EmiratesAir won't allow me. Then back to square one - how do I know that other airlines will?

Comment: I would say call the airlines, specifically at the airport you are planning to depart from. Another option is to travel to your home country and then travel to Dubai from there, even if it is transit. This may end up being expensive, though.

Comment: @Nivas some airlines have said "allowed". Others, when asked a second time, said "ohh, actually not". There's no possibility to travel to my home country

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.